# SciLAB - File reading and displaying the contents

Tags: file, scilab

How do I display the file contents after writing into the file in scilab?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean opening the file in the editor you can you the builtin `scinotes` editor ([docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/scinotes.html)) as such

```
my_file_path = "my_dir/my_file.txt";
scinotes(my_file_path);
```

It is also possbile to use a predefined other editor with the `editor` command ([docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/editor.html)):

```
my_file_path = "my_dir/my_file.txt";
editor(my_file_path);
```

If you want to read a file and display it's contents you can use `mgetl` ([docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/mgetl.html)) and `disp`

```
my_file_path = "my_dir/my_file.txt";
fd=mopen(my_file_path,'r');
my_txt = mgetl(fd,10);
mclose(fd);
disp(my_txt)
```